# Google Spreadsheets: Format value if it is public holiday

Tags: google-sheets

I want the Date column to format those dates that are public holidays to be red color. e.g.

```
Date
------ 
14/05/2015
14/05/2015
15/05/2015  
16/05/2015
....    
**25/05/2015**   <-- this is red color because of us holiday
```

I have tried using the built in function of formatting value based on condition. But it seems it can only compare the column with 1 single holiday for each condition.

What is the easiest way to do ? Can I grab the google calendar for holiday and compare the dates with the calendar in google spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Akshin Jalilov. 
So assume:

Column A is the dates,

Column B in another holiday spreedsheet is the holidays

At Column C, I check if it is public holiday or Sunday:

> =COUNTIF(INDIRECT("holiday!$B$2:$B$14"),"="&A2)+COUNTIF(WEEKDAY($A2),"=1")

If it is holiday or sunday, then the field value is >= 1

Then I add conditional formatting for the dates

> Column A2:A

using customn condition:

> =C19:C>=1

Comment: This works. You can also use conditional formatting in Column A with the formula I edited in my reply. That way you won't need to use Column C.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a conditional formatting with a custom formula to check if the date is in the range with your holiday dates, and if it is, colour it red.

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("holiday!$B$2:$B$14"),"="&A2)+COUNTIF(WEEKDAY($A2),"=1")>=1
```

Comment: If you make the holiday dates a name range ("Holidays"), and you don't want Sundays to be coloured, then the formula can be simplified as: `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Holidays"),A2)=1`